# Use result from inputbox in multiple commands

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use one inputbox result to run two SQL statements. When I run it, I get the inputbox each time. Is there a way to show it once, and use that single result in both statements?

```
result = InputBox("Enter the solicitor name:")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE addresses SET sol1=result WHERE sol1 Is Null AND disc1=True;")
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE addresses SET sol2=result WHERE sol2 Is Null AND disc2=True;")
```

Comment: This should work... have you declared `result` as a `String`?

Comment: It is much better to use a form. It is much better to use parameters. It is also better to use Execute against an instance of the database. In the above example result must be in quotes and outside of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concatenate result:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE addresses SET sol1 = '" & result & "' WHERE sol1 Is Null AND disc1=True;")
```

To allow for O'Neal:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE addresses SET sol1 = """ & result & """ WHERE sol1 Is Null AND disc1=True;")
```

Comment: It is better to use parameters as I commented above. This is unsafe. I am also a little concerned that two columns need to be updated. In addition, your quotes will not work for O'Connell Street.

Comment: Yes, but that didn't answer the question. My choice would be to use DAO and update a recordset.

Comment: It used to be usual to do more than just answer the question, it used to be important to provide guidance. The quotes you used are still a problem.

Comment: While SQL injection is difficult in Jet/ACE, the above code may be run against an SQL Server back-end.

Comment: Thank you, Gustav. That worked.

To answer your question, Fionnuala, because they are on different rows.